# Cache manifest spaces in file name

Tags: ios, html, safari

I've noticed that you can not use spaces in file paths in the cache manifest file. It seems weird since you can actually have spaces in file names. I happen to have a lot of important spaces in a lot of file names that I really can not do without. Right now every browser ignores everything that comes after a space in a file name. Any solutions besides just not using spaces?

Comment: maybe an %20, because the space in file name will be converted to this sign.

Answer (score 0):

Replacing spaces in filenames in the appcache manifest with `%20` seems to work. This doesn't require renaming any of the files.